# Ленивая загрузка ajax при скролле

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lazyloading

Делаю ленивую загрузку при скроле. Все работает хорошо, контент загружается. Хочу добавить спинер, чтобы прокручивался немного до того, как загрузится контент. При загрузке первого блока он появляется, а дальше при скролле я его не вижу. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", lazyScroll)

function lazyScroll() {
  if (!newsBox.classList.contains('_loading')) {
    loadMore();
  }
}

const hadleGetData = () => {
  $.ajax({
    url: `json_news/${visable_f}/${visible}`,
    type: 'get',
    success: function(response) {
      max_size = response.max
      const data = response.all_news
      loadBox.classList.remove('not-visable')
      setTimeout(() => {
        data.map(news => {
          loadBox.classList.add('not-visable')
          //console.log(news.title_newsmebelain)
          newsBox.innerHTML += `
          <div class="news-element ">
            <img src="${news.main_image}">
            <div class="news-description">
              <h2 class="title">${news.title}</h2>
              <div class="date">${news.date}</div>
              <a href="news/${news.slug}" class="btn">Подробнее</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        `
          newsBox.classList.remove('_loading')
          if (max_size) {
            console.log('done')
            loadBox.innerHTML = ""
          }
        }, 1500)

      })

    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
}

hadleGetData()

function loadMore() {
  const loadMoreBlockPos = newsBox.getBoundingClientRect().top + pageYOffset;
  const loadMoreBlockHeight = newsBox.offsetHeight;
  if (pageYOffset > (loadMoreBlockPos + loadMoreBlockHeight) - windowHeight) {
    newsBox.classList.add('_loading')
    visable_f = visible
    visible += 8
    hadleGetData()
  }
}
```